# We define sequence $(a_{n})_{n}$ with $a_{n} = f(\frac{1}{n})$. Prove that sequence $(a_{n})_{n}$ is convergent.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Let $ f: (0,\infty) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a differentiable function such that $f'$ is bounded. We define the sequence $(a_{n})_{n}$ with $a_{n} = f(\frac{1}{n})$. Prove that the sequence  $(a_{n})_{n}$ is convergent.

Any help?

Comment: $|a_m-a_n|=|f(1/m)-f(1/n)|=|f'(t)||1/m-1/n|$ for some $t=t_{m,n}\in (1/m,1/n)$.

Answer (score 1):

By MVT $|a_n-a_m| \leq M|\frac 1 n -\frac  1 m |\to 0$ where $M$ is a bound for $|f'(x)|$. It follows that $(a_n)$ is a Cauchy sequence, hence convergent.